# IS_FREELANCER errors on updating to 2.5.5

Tags: updating

Getting this error when updating to 2.5.5 from 2.5.4:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant IS_FREELANCER - assumed 'IS_FREELANCER'
Filename: core/EE_Config.php(197) : eval()'d code
Line Number: 1
```

I updated using the quick method via this blog post: http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.5.5-released

Do I need to set a config variable for IS_FREELANCER in my config.php?

Comment: Copied over files from the /system/expressionengine/core directory, but now I have several other areas littered in the CP with errors like: `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant IS_FREELANCER - assumed 'IS_FREELANCER'
Filename: _shared/footer.php
Line Number: 5`

Comment: My version number is showing up as Freelancer v2.5.5 for some reason, too.

Comment: Make sure you have all the latest files from the EE download archive. There should be no instance of "IS_FREELANCER" anywhere in 2.5.4 or 2.5.5. Perhaps your original 2.5.4 upgrade wasn't complete.

Comment: I tried a typical EE upgrade using [these instructions](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html) and got a couple bizarre errors. First, immediately when I tried to upgrade I got [this error](http://cl.ly/Lu5J). When I tried to run the upgrade again I just get [this error](http://cl.ly/Lul7). Nothing in PHP/Apache/MySQL error logs.

Comment: Looks like this is a Structure issue. I changed $debug to 1 in admin.php and got numerous Structure errors. Will report back.

Comment: Aaron, did this get resolved? Can you post your fix if it did?

Comment: Just posted an answer, Anna. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the Structure crew for some help and they supplied me with a hotfix for the issue. I believe it is [built into the stable version now](http://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3286-php-errors-when-upgrading-to-expressionengine-255).